# Visual Studio 2015 Code Coverage threw - Failed to enable constraints

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, code-coverage

I'm trying to run a code coverage in VS2015 Enterprise and get the following error.

> Exception was thrown: Code Coverage Analysis engine threw exception(s):
>   Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

The solution and the projects are migrated from VS2012. 
The code coverage works fine for simple brand new projects.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, did anyone find any workable solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error message and it stopped when I deleted the TestResults folder in the root of my solution.

Comment: @ivan-monteiro TestResults folder is created by VS whenever the solution is loaded, so I don't think it's possible to remove it completely (the folder is recreated anyway). TestResults folder actually contains the coverage files which VS2015 can collect but cannot open for whatever reason.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Worked fine yesterday. I deleted the folder and re-ran the tests and performed code coverage on selected tests. Got the same error again.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to two tests in the same testassembly having the same name. I've had the same problem myself.

Comment: please, clarify, because if I create a simple test project with 2 methods (Tests) which  have the same name it still works fine. It must be something else